# Mercurial: How can I keep stuff locally only?

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-queue, mercurial-extension

We have some restrictions on what we are allowed to put in our central Mercurial repository.

Is there some way I can keep stuff in my local Hg repository, without having it  pushed to the central one?

Note:

1. The files might be connected to files in the central repository (branches for example).
2. Local stuff might later be incorporated in the central repository.

Comment: I haven't used it but what about [Shelve Extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ShelveExtension)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using branches, you can set their visibility to `secret`. This will prevent them to be pushed.

```
hg phase --secret --force my-branch
```

When you want to share, you change their phase to `draft` and then they will be automatically collected during a push operation.

See `hg help phases` for more information.

Comment: This sound very simple :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could also use [Mercurial Queues](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/MqExtension). With MQ, you can work with patches (which are changesets) and update or re-order them based on changes in the official repository. This will also make it easier to incorporate some or all of your changes into the main repository or just discard them later.

Answer (score 0):

Commit to your local repo, then push to the remote repo when you are finished.

You can push to your local repo as well, but from my understanding that is where your current development is?

Comment: It might never be "finished" (It might not be in the central repository for  long time).

Comment: I understand the principle.  I would have to use a more "granular" push.  Would pull/update be as easy?

Comment: Yeah pull/update would be easy enough... mercurial is smart enough.. but true conflicts (modification of same line) will have to be fixed manually

Comment: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/programming-and-development/a-development-workflow-for-mercurial/3237

Answer (score 0):

I think you want [Shelve Extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ShelveExtension) or [Attic Extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/AtticExtension).

The other option is if your using a newer Hg with better branching you can just fork the central repo somewhere like bitbucket and use that as your repository for your temporary stuff and potentially branch that.

Finally you could also just use `.hgignore` but that could be problematic later when someone does check in the file with the same name.